# Get the image filename by first characters using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a folder with images that have long filenames, but they all have unique product ID numbers at the beginning

> e.g. **1023**-Very-Long-Image-Name.jpg.

What I'm trying to do is to get full image filename into my javascript, by just using this unique ID number.

> e.g. I need to find an image with ID **1023**, which is this one - **1023-Very-Long-Image-Name.jpg**

All unique IDs stored in JSON database. So below is an example of my code:

```js
$('.choose-range-cta').click(function () {
  var rowID = $(this).attr("id");
  var stylesTable = JSON.parse(stylesDB);
  var styleHTML = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < stylesTable.length; i++) {
   if (stylesTable[i].collectionID == rowID) {
     
    var blockTitle = stylesTable[i].styleName;
    var blockPrice = stylesTable[i].fromPrice;
    var blockSize = stylesTable[i].size;
    var blockImageID = stylesTable[i].frontImageID;
    
    styleHTML += "<div class=\"col-lg-4 style-block\"><a href=\"#\"><span class=\"style-name\">" + blockTitle + "</span><span class=\"from-price\">from &pound;" + blockPrice + "</span><span class=\"cta\">Select</span><div class=\"img-box\"><img src=\"" + ImagePath + blockImageID +"\"></div><span class=\"copy\">" + blockSize + "</span></a></div>";
   }
  }
  $('#style-list').html(styleHTML);
 });
```

Comment: Can you show your data format & what you've tried so far to achieve this?

Comment: "I have a list.." - where? what kind of list?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, I have updated the question. All images are in a folder on server.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your list is an array, use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
var imageArray = [
    '1021-Don-Long-Image-Name.jpg',
    '1022-Very-Long-Image-Name.jpg',
    '1023-Dan-Long-Image-Name.jpg',
    '1024-BobLong-Image-Name.jpg'
];

function getName(data, id) {
    return data.filter(function (el) {
        return el.substring(0, 4) === id;
    })[0];
}

var name = getName(imageArray, '1023'); // 1023-Dan-Long-Image-Name.jpg
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uf5vLcgc/2)

Comment: You should probably constraint it: `return el.indexOf(id + '-') === 0`; Since `10235` would match too and `21023` too

Comment: Not sure if the next character is a dash or not so I just went with substring instead.

Comment: Yes I can see, it is a nice move, but I think it still would be a problem if the id is less than 4 chars long (I understood up to 4 chars, but not of a fixed size)

Comment: "All unique IDs are limited to 4 characters": from the post. I'm assuming that means they're at least 4, but no longer.

Comment: The thing I was thinking about, happen when it is less than 4 chars (not in my first comment, in the second one). For example '123-bla.jpg': `getName('123')` -> `undefined` because `'123-' !== '123'`